# How to use the Color we set in createMuiTheme Function of App.js file in child component in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I am new to react. Actually I set primary color to my react application using muithemeprovider. As Below:

[image]

Each time when this App gets loaded the primary color will set up randomly. Now  I need to set the same color to the button present inside some child components. So I need to get the value of the primary color inside child components. I didnt get any clue to get the value of primary color in other component. Request your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to export your theme, and then pass it into the [ThemeProvider](https://material-ui.com/styles/api/#themeprovider) component which you should implement at the root of your application. This will pass it down the React tree and so make your theme available to every child component.

Within each child component where you intend to use the theme, you can then call the theme and its properties directly. For example, if you were trying to style a Button component, you would do so like this:

```
<Button
 type="submit"
 fullWidth
 variant="contained"
 color="primary"
>
  Sign In
</Button>
```

The 'color="primary"' refers to the primary colour attribute set within your theme, this is then accessible due to the implementation of the ThemeProvider component.

Comment: @SuRa Please can you post your complete code so that we can fully see the issue you are having?